# Does h2o.kmeans() make predictions based on euclidean distance?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, h2o, euclidean-distance

I created a clustering model using h2o.kmeans(). The modeling dataset was standardized by scale() in R first.

The model has five clusters and the coordinates of the centroids are:

```
CENTROID    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
1   -0.646544   -0.6322714  -0.5101907  -0.2980412  -1.6182105  -1.7939725  -1.8194372  -1.82349    -1.8174061  -1.8069266 -2.2213561   -2.2618561  -2.2170297  -2.2004509  -2.196722   -2.2267695  -2.2536694  -2.2653944  -2.1599764  -2.2074994 -1.9114193   -2.78E-16
2   -0.2505012  -0.2582746  -0.2542313  -0.3205136  0.2912933   0.3239872   0.3236214   0.3231876   0.3234663   0.309818 0.362641   0.3800735   0.3615138   0.3542787   0.350817    0.3583391   0.375764    0.3715018   0.3533203   0.3533025   0.2651153 3.72E-15
3   0.4237044   0.4421857   0.408422    0.6620773   0.2371281   0.2592748   0.2597783   0.2782299   0.258803    0.3129833   0.4157714 0.3704712 0.3948566   0.4137049   0.4289137   0.4229101   0.3904031   0.4323851   0.3984215   0.442518    0.5278553   1.00E+00
4   2.2426614   2.2450805   2.0475964   1.5666675   0.2249847   0.2887632   0.3391117   0.3224008   0.3375972   0.3617759 0.5063836 0.4805747   0.5226613   0.5097081   0.5196333   0.5136624   0.4780912   0.4686772   0.4743151   0.5357567   0.5734882 8.24E-01
5   4.4718381   4.5243432   4.8917335   5.223828    0.2374653   0.3096633   0.3215417   0.3326531   0.3189998   0.414707    0.5065842 0.5113028 0.558864    0.5482378   0.543278    0.5436269   0.5204451   0.5341745   0.5096259   0.6486469   0.6595461   9.89E-01
```

When using the model to make predictions for new data, mostly the result makes sense, which returns the cluster whose centroid has the shortest euclidean distance to the data point; however, sometimes (about 5%) the prediction is off. For example, for a data point as below:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
-0.2001578  -0.2485784  -0.3008685  -0.005366991    0.2624246   0.3142725   0.3074037   0.3221539   0.3033765   0.3403944 0.3557642 0.3810387   0.4848038   0.2788213   0.544491    0.2838926   0.2899755   0.3963652   0.2594092   0.3083141   0.463528    1
```

The prediction is cluster 3; however, the euclidean distance between the data point and centroids are:

```
cluster 1: 10
cluster 2: 1.11
cluster 3: 1.39
cluster 4: 4.53
cluster 5: 9.97.
```

Based on the calculation above, the data point should be assigned to cluster 2, not 3.

Is it a bug or h2o.kmeans() uses other methods instead of euclidean distance for prediction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as stated in the [K-Means documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/k-means.html), it uses Euclidean distance.

If you can provide a reproducible example showing that this is a bug, please file a [bug report](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV).  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Erin. A bug report has been created : https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5419. The table in the bug report is messed up so I also attached the data as an excel file.